# Change Orientation of a Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-orientation

I have a problem. I have an App, which has a fix orientation (portrait) set in the manifest.xml.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

But I do want to change the orientation of an `Dialog`, that I create programmatically in one of my fragments. Problem is, that the `super` method `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`is never been called, because of my manifest declaration.

Is it possible to detect that the phone has been turned and change the orientation of the dialog (Without destroying / recreating everything like normally)?

EDIT:

"`Activity` and `Fragments` should stay in portrait mode, `Dialog` should detect changes and orient"

Hope this question is understandable ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Should only the dialog orient? Do the fragment which creates the dialog should not orient?

Comment: exactly like that. Activity and Fragments stay in portrait, Dialog detects changes and orient

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? This is actually exactly what I need right now

Comment: Ohh.. a lot of time passed. I'm Not Sure. I will take a look into my codes after work. Haven't Coded Android for a while so i'm not sure where to look..

Comment: Still haven't found the answer?

Comment: @ᴛʜᴇᴘᴀᴛᴇʟ Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @Supradip.M Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that a viable solution would be to remove the android:screenOrientation tag and then override the onConfigurationChanged() method to do what you need.

Comment: It would do the job, but I'm curious if there was another solution, to just orient the dialog

Answer (score 0):

We had to do this in a fullscreen dialog launched from a service.

```
override fun onStart() {
    window?.attributes?.screenOrientation = SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    super.onStart()
}
```

and it works fine